# Exchange 2010 to 2013 duplicated user after migration

Tags: exchange, exchange-migration

I have the following problem:

By migrating a user from the databese EX2010 to EX2013 via the Exchange Admin Center a second user/duplicate is getting created and the original mailbox/isn't accessible anymore. The mails can still be found by logging in with the duplicate user.

It seems like there is a workaround for that problem for an older Exchange version. 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ashour/2015/08/28/fix-duplication-in-default-folders-kb3031133-kb3069501-kb2991934/

Why is that exact problem still happening with the current version I'm working with (Exchange CU19) and can I somehow solve that without deleting all duplicates after a migration of alls users?

Thank you

Comment: How did you migrated the users from 2010 to 2013 via New-MoveRequest (see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/302-move-exchange-2010-2013-user-to-exchange-2016.html)) via an cooexistence environment between Exchange 2010 and 2013 (see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/206-migrate-from-exchange-2010-to-exchange-2016.html))?

Comment: The first link already helped me. I used the Exchange PowerShell for the migration instead of the web interface and migration batches.
Thanks!

Comment: great, i added that as an possible answer so we can close the question then once you can accept the answer (might be possible after 24h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, try to use the

*[New-MoveRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351123(v=exchg.141).aspx)*

as explained for example [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/302-move-exchange-2010-2013-user-to-exchange-2016.html).